# Newbie Rails 3 - select_tag - numeric values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a form I want a selectbox with the values 1 to 30, and store the value in a db-column. Is there a helper for this? I looked at the `select_tag` but did not find a good solution.

Can someone help?

Comment: Someone will once you accept a few answers to previous questions.

Comment: if you weren't sure it's the checkmark that then turns green.

Answer (score 1):

Use the select_tag when you require a drop-down selection box populated with data not sourced from a database

erb:

```
<%= f.select "make_num", 1..30 %>
```

haml:

```
= f.select "make_num", 1..50
```

or (better MVC)
**create the my_range = 1..30 in your controller**

```
my_range = 1..30
```

and then in your view:

erb:

```
<%= f.select "make_num", my_range %>
```

haml:

```
= f.select "make_num", my_range
```

or (**best MVC**)

Use clem's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the acceptable range of values in my model

```
# app/models/widget.rb
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  RATING_VALUES = (1..10)
end
```

And then I can reference that in the view:

```
# app/views/widgets/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @widget do |f|
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.select :rating, Widget::RATING_VALUES %>
  </fieldset>

  <!-- etc -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 Yes I like that more than my solution.  Model is better than controller always.  Thanks Clem!

Comment: Good to hear! If you could accept this (or any) answer on this question I'd appreciate it.